# How to display nested json arrays into html table with material angular

Tags: html, json, angular, angular-material

I am trying to display a nested json array into my material angular table. My data works fine if my json does not have nested arrays.

**Json**

```
{
"rows": [
    {
        "mst": {
            "field": "createDate",
            "value": "2017-06-02"
        },
        "gsc": {
            "field": "Account/Audit/Creation/Date",
            "value": "2017-06-02"
        }
    },
    {
        "mst": {
            "field": "startDate"
        },
        "gsc": {
            "field": "startDate"
        }
    },
    {
        "mst": {
            "field": "status",
            "value": "ACTIVE"
        },
        "gscs": [
            {
                "field": "Account/LineOfBusiness/Type~Status",
                "value": "C~A"
            },
            {
                "field": "Account/LineOfBusiness/Type~Status",
                "value": "I~A"
            }                
        ],
        "gscvalue": "Active"
    },
    {
        "mst": {
            "field": "statusDate"
        },
        "gsc": {
            "field": "statusDate"
        }
    },
    {
        "mst": {
            "field": "statusReason"
        },
        "gsc": {
            "field": "statusReason"
        }
    },
    {
        "mst": {
            "field": "deliveryMethod",
            "value": "PAPER"
        },
        "gscs": [
            {
                "field": "Electronic",
                "value": "N"
            },
            {
                "field": "ElectronicOutsourced",
                "value": "N"
            },
            {
                "field": "Hardcopy",
                "value": "Y"
            }
        ],
        "gscvalue": "Paper"
    },
    {
        "mst": {
            "field": "statementFormat",
            "value": "Standard"
        },
        "gsc": {
            "field": "?"
        }
    },
    {
        "mst": {
            "field": "statementLanguagePreference",
            "value": "Spanish"
        },
        "gsc": {
            "field": "Account/Language",
            "value": "S"
        },
        "gscvalue": "Spanish"
    },
    {
        "mst": {
            "field": "type",
            "value": "RES"
        },
        "gsc": {
            "field": "Account/Type",
            "value": "RES"
        }
    }
]
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8" *ngIf="rows?.length>0">
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

<ng-container matColumnDef="mst Fields">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> mst Fields </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="tablePadding"> {{row.mst.field}} </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="mst">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> mst value </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.mst.value}} </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="gsc Fields">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> gsc Fields </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.gsc.field}} </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="gsc">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> gsc value </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.gsc.value}} </td>           
</ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let row"></tr>
```

**modal.ts**

```
export class ResultField {
field: string;
value: string;
valueList: string[];
}

export class ResultRow {
mst: ResultField;
gsc: ResultField;
gscs: ResultField[];
gscValue: String;
}
```

My current table will display data all the way up until it reaches mst.field{status}. I get an error

```
SystemComponent.html:29 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'field' of undefined
```

I understand this error is coming because of my current logic in my html. How can I resolve this?

Hence, I don't want gscs.field in a separate column I want those values into gsc.field column and the gscValue in the gsc.value column.

**Attempt**

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="gsc Fields">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> gsc Fields </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" *ngIf="row.gsc.field"> {{row.gsc.field}} </td>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" *ngIf="row.gsc.field"> {{row.gscs.field}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

But with angular logic there can only be one * directives in a tag.

My closest reference is [Need to display Nested JSON Object in Material Data Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55511432/need-to-display-nested-json-object-in-material-data-table)
but there were no solid answers.

**Attempt 2**

I tried using a simpler approach just to get my data printed.

```
<div>
  <h1>Testing</h1>

  <div *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <!-- <p *ngIf="row.gsc.field">{{row.gsc.field}}</p>
    <p *ngIf="row.gsc.value">{{row.gsc.value}}</p> -->
    <p>{{row.mst.field}}</p>
    <p>{{row.mst.value}}</p>   


  <div *ngFor= "let gscs of row.gscs">
    <p *ngIf="gscs.field">{{gscs.field}}</p>
    <p *ngIf="gscs.value">{{gscs.value}}</p>
</div>
<p *ngIf = "row.gscvalue">{{row.gscvalue}}</p>
  </div>  
</div>
```

With this code snippet, I am able to pull the nested values however I am getting the same error as above when I uncomment these two lines.

```
<!-- <p *ngIf="row.gsc.field">{{row.gsc.field}}</p>
<p *ngIf="row.gsc.value">{{row.gsc.value}}</p> -->
```

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'field' of undefined

With the JSON I provided above, I want to create a table that looks like this following picture.

[image: Final Output]

Comment: so when there's an array, you want multiple cells to represent that?

Comment: @bryan60 Yes. That's correct. It can be gscs.field only if we cannot set gscs.field and gscs.value in the same cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems like you just need to nest your `ngIf`:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="gsc Fields">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> gsc Fields </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <ng-container *ngIf="row.gsc?.field; else fieldArray">
      {{row.gsc.field}} 
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #fieldArray>
      <div class="sub-cell" *ngFor="let field of row.gscs"> <!-- need the appropriate css -->
        {{field.field}} {{field.value}}
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

and in your value column you want more like:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="gsc">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> gsc value </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.gsc?.value || row.gscvalue}} </td>           
</ng-container>
```

not sure this is 100% but should be close

Comment: Thank you Bryan! You are a life savior! This helped a lot. Will provide you the bounty once the timer is up.